# How to place Image in an arc in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-graphics

Following is my code for ticket like background.I used multiple sources on google to achieve this

```
    class TicketShapeBackground(
    private val circleRadius: Dp,
    private val cornerSize: CornerSize
) : Shape {

    override fun createOutline(size: Size, layoutDirection: LayoutDirection, density: Density): Outline {
        return Outline.Generic(path = getPath(size, density))
    }

    private fun getPath(size: Size, density: Density): Path {
        val roundedRect = RoundRect(size.toRect(), CornerRadius(cornerSize.toPx(size, density)))
        val roundedRectPath = Path().apply { addRoundRect(roundedRect) }
        return Path.combine(operation = PathOperation.Intersect, path1 = roundedRectPath, path2 = getTicketPath(size, density))
    }

    private fun getTicketPath(size: Size, density: Density): Path {
        val middleX = size.width.div(other = 2)
        val middleY = size.height.div(other = 2)
        val circleRadiusInPx = with(density) { circleRadius.toPx() }
        return Path().apply {
            reset()
           
            lineTo(x = 0F, y = 0F)
       
            lineTo(middleX, y = 0F)


           
            arcTo(
                rect = Rect(
                    left = middleX.minus(circleRadiusInPx),
                    top = 0F.minus(circleRadiusInPx),
                    right = middleX.plus(circleRadiusInPx),
                    bottom = circleRadiusInPx
                ),
                startAngleDegrees = 180F,
                sweepAngleDegrees = -180F,
                forceMoveTo = false
            )
            // Draw line to top right
            lineTo(x = size.width, y = 0F)
           
            lineTo(x = size.width, y = middleY)


           // lineTo(x = size.width, y = 0F)

           // lineTo(x = size.width, y = middleY)

            arcTo(
                rect = Rect(
                    left = size.width - circleRadiusInPx,
                    top = middleY - circleRadiusInPx,
                    right = size.width + circleRadiusInPx,
                    bottom = middleY + circleRadiusInPx
                ),
                startAngleDegrees = 270f,
                sweepAngleDegrees = -180F,
                forceMoveTo = false
            )
            lineTo(x = size.width, y = size.height)


          
            lineTo(middleX, y = size.height)
           
            lineTo(x = 0F, y = size.height)


            lineTo(x = size.width, y = size.height)

            lineTo(0F, size.height)

            lineTo(x = 0F, y = size.height)
            arcTo(
                rect = Rect(
                    left = 0F - circleRadiusInPx,
                    top = middleY - circleRadiusInPx,
                    right = circleRadiusInPx,
                    bottom = middleY + circleRadiusInPx
                ),
                startAngleDegrees = 90f,
                sweepAngleDegrees = -180F,
                forceMoveTo = false
            )

            lineTo(x = 0F, y = 0F)
        }
    }
}
```

and use it like

```
 Box(
                Modifier.clip(TicketShapeBackground(34.dp, CornerSize(5.dp)))

                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .background(Color.Red)
            ) { }
```

Now the arc at the top ie after lineTo(middleX, y = 0F) I need to place an image inside the arc,like a circle image. How to achieve it. One way could be using a Box maybe but not sure how to do it, also I am not sure if it is a clean solution.
Any help is appreciated .Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

[image]

```
val radius = 34.dp
Box(Modifier.background(Color.White)) {
    Image(
        imageVector = Icons.Default.Face,
        modifier = Modifier
            .align(Alignment.TopCenter)
            .offset(y = -radius)
            .size(radius * 2),
        contentDescription = "top arc image",
    )
    Box(
        Modifier
            .clip(TicketShapeBackground(radius, CornerSize(5.dp)))
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Red)
    )
}
```

Comment: This is awesome, thanks , exactly what I wanted :) .
Would you please not mind explaining that how you reached the conclusion of using this logic? 
.align(Alignment.TopCenter)
            .offset(y = -radius)
            .size(radius * 2)

Comment: As the image should be at the top center, using `align` seemed as the easiest solution. Then image size has to be the same size as the arc it's in. And finally we have to move it up so it's center coincide with arc's center. Checkout [This](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Jetpack-Compose-Tutorials) tutorial on compose from SO member Thracian. Also there is [List of Compose modifiers](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/modifiers-list) with sections on drawing, position etc. @Pritish